# How can I remove the border on a Dialog Window with Dynamic Layout controls?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, layout, dynamic, mfc

I have a WIN32 application that uses a main dialog window as background and several alternative dialogs that can appear in front of the main window. These overlay dialogs should not have any border because they need to appear to be part of the main window.
Everything was working well until I activated Dynamic Layout on the controls in an overlay dialog.  It then acquired a thin border with drop shadow, a thin top bar that was sometimes windows top bar color and sometimes white, and the dialog became independently resizable.  I don't want this, I want the overlay dialog to resize only with the main dialog window.
How can I force the dialog to have No Border?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer to my original question is to put the following code in the overloaded OnInitDialog() after the call to the base class.
`LONG_PTR wStyle = GetWindowLongPtr(m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE); // Get the current style`
`wStyle &= ~WS_SIZEBOX; // Mask out the style bit(s) we don't want`
`SetWindowLongPtr(m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE, wStyle); // And set the new style`

Comment: This is repeating the other answer for the most part, except it replaces `WS_BORDER` with `WS_SIZEBOX` (same as `WS_THICKFRAME` for resizable border) and also removes system menu which wasn't asked in the question. You can click the check mark to accept the answer you want.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.  I am still learning to use this website correctly.  I have edited my answer and clicked the check mark.  I wanted to put in a definitive answer, in case anyone else has the same problem.  I felt it was important to restate it in full because neither of the earlier answers had any affect.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the style of a dialog window in your override of the `OnInitDialog()` member function, if that window is created using a custom class derived from `CDialog` or `CDialogEx`, or something similar. (If not, you'll need to somehow 'intercept' the window's creation process.)

Assuming you *have* overridden `OnInitDialog()`, the process will be along these lines:

```cpp
BOOL MyDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
    BOOL answer = CDialog::OnInitDialog();                 // Call base class stuff
    LONG_PTR wStyle = GetWindowLongPtr(m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE); // Get the current style
    wStyle &= ~WS_BORDER;   // Here, we mask out the style bit(s) we want to remove
    SetWindowLongPtr(m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE, wStyle);           // And set the new style

    // ... other code as required ...

    return answer;
}
```

Note: It is important to call the base class `OnInitDialog()` *before* you attempt to modify the window's style; otherwise, the window may not be in a 'completed' state, and any changes you make may be reverted.

---

As mentioned in the comment by [IInspectable](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1889329/iinspectable), it *may* be possible (or even better) to modify the style (taking out the `WS_BORDER` attribute) in an override of the `PreCreateWindow()` function:

```cpp
BOOL MyDialog::PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT &cs)
{
    if (!CDialog::PreCreateWindow(cs)) return FALSE;
    cs.style &= ~WS_BORDER;
    return TRUE;
}
```

Again, [as shown here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/changing-the-styles-of-a-window-created-by-mfc?view=msvc-160), you should call the base class member *before* modifying the style.

Comment: I haven't checked this, but it's possibly better to modify the window style in a [PreCreateWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#precreatewindow) override. This will ensure that everyone sees the same style through a window's lifetime.

Comment: @IInspectable Yeah - that may be a more universal option. However, I'm not *entirely* sure what tricks the MFC Framework may do in terms of modifying the style during later base class routines, such as `OnInitDialog()`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.  I tried both PreCreateWindow() and OnInitDialog() (being careful to call the base class function first)  but neither of them worked.  I still get the annoying border.

Comment: @Thunderdonkey Hmmm. Try setting the style (end ex-style) explicitly to only those flags you want. Or read those values and see what they are being set to?

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  This code solved the problem.  
`   LONG_PTR wStyle = GetWindowLongPtr(m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE); // Get the current style  
    wStyle &= (~WS_SYSMENU && WS_SIZEBOX);   // Here, we mask out the style bit(s) we want to remove  
    SetWindowLongPtr(m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE, wStyle);           // And set the new style  `
Interestingly, the value of wStyle before the correction was 0x840c004c but 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-styles
does not list any function for the lower four bytes.

Comment: That `(~WS_SYSMENU && WS_SIZEBOX)` looks ***very*** suspicious (logical `&&` where there should probably be a bitwise operator). Maybe you meant `~(WS_SYSMENU | WS_SIZEBOX)` ? If it works, then it's just (un)lucky.